# openssl_encrypt cipher decypted using Crypto JS

Tags: javascript, php, aes, cryptojs

I have a custom payment method on WordPress that processes the payment through a NodeJS API. For obvious reasons, I should encrypt some data, like credit card numbers and cvv2s.

This is how I encrypt my fields in PHP:

```
        $cvv2 = openssl_encrypt(
        $_POST['cvv2'], 
        'AES-256-CBC',
        "2c2702d12c747661358dfe9b77425628", // Testing key, thats why its set like this
        0
    );
```

This is the output ciphered text: CRqJRoqHriB7X/u1bwSE1Q==

This is how I try to decrypt in JS

```
const key = "2cea02d12c747661358dfe9b77425628";

const dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cvv2,key);

console.log(dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```

But the output is always an empty string.

This is me decrypting it using an [online tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Ay1.png)

[image]

**I am really frustrated as I cannot seem to make this work, no matter how much I read online.
What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CryptoJS code, the key must be passed as `WordArray` (using a suitable encoder) and the zero IV (16 0x00 values) used implicitly in the PHP code must be specified explicitly.
The ciphertext must be passed as `CipherParams` object or Base64 encoded (the latter is implicitly converted to a `CipherParams` object):

```js
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("2cea02d12c747661358dfe9b77425628");
const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([], 16);
const ciphertext = "CRqJRoqHriB7X/u1bwSE1Q==";

const dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, {iv:  iv});

console.log(dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
console.log(dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Note that a static IV is insecure.

Comment: You're a saviour. Thank you very much!